# Time series plot using netcdf data in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a time series for a 3d plot. I know that the variable must be made 1d inorder to make it viable for the time series plot. Actually I want the data within a box of latitude and longitude. So if anyone can help me in this regard of how to plot it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try these out and see if they work for your use-case.

Plotting geospatial data in Python:
https://towardsdatascience.com/geopandas-101-plot-any-data-with-a-latitude-and-longitude-on-a-map-98e01944b972

Using matplotlib for simple animations:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-matplotlib-for-animations/

Comment: Matplotlib has pretty good documentation. Why not directly link to the tutorial from the matplotlib docs? https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/animation_tutorial.html